# Cleaner regex for removing characters before dot or slash

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Is there a cleaner regex than the following? I know I can search for two different regex at the same time by combining them with `|`.

I'm removing everything before the first occurrence of a `.` or `-` by the following regex and the extra space after these.

```
re.sub("^[^-]*- |^[^.]*. ", "", some string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.sub(r"^[^.-]*[.-]\s*","",some_string)
```

You can try this.